# using simplehtmldom to find inner content

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Can `simplehtmldom` be used to find a DIV who's inner content (not a attribute) is equal to a `$_POST` value?

I need to check that a `DIV` with a inner content of lets say `John doe` doesn't already exist before a page is modified using `FWRITE` - The value being compared against will be given to `simplehtmldom` by a `$_POST` value. None of this goes in/through a database and if i missed something that addresses this in `simplehtmldom` doc's then sorry in advance, i just didn't see it.

Assuming that: `$_POST['data'] = "John Doe";` and the current page has:

```
<div id="aaa"> John Doe </div>
<div id="bbb"> Jane Doe </div>
<div id="ccc"> Mike Doe</div>
```

Would this below work to find the `DIV` with inner content `"John Doe"`?

```
$html = file_get_html("$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']");
$result = $html->find("$_POST['data']");
if ($result !=="") {do this....} else {do this instead...}
```

Comment: Why don't you do this with JS ?

Comment: There is still some PHP processing that has to be done depending on if the content is found, I have not had best of luck passing JS values over to PHP in the past. But i will look into your suggestion if simplehtmldom wont work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its in the documentation regarding getting texts inside a tag. You need to use `->innertext` magic attribute. Just check whether that particular value exists using `stripos()`.

Example:

```
$found = false;
foreach($html->find('div') as $div) {
    if(stripos($div->innertext, $_POST['data']) !== false) {
        $found = true;
    }
}

if($found) {
    // john doe exists
} else {
    // he doesn't exist in each div
}
```

My personal preference:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('your_url');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
if($xpath->query('//div[contains(., "'.$_POST['data'].'")]')->length > 0) {
    // john doe is there
} else {
    // john doe isn't
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that really counts as doing it with simple_html_dom

Comment: @pguardiario at first glance your answer seems to be best and inline with what i asked, but no matter how i did it I kept getting a PHP error reporting from advanced_html_dom.php - Since KEvins answer worked I have accepted it, even though its not simple/advance_html_dom

Answer (score 1):

Simple can't do that. You'll want to switch to [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/) and do:

```
$html->find('div[text=" John Doe "]', 0);
```

Comment: wow this one's good too actually this is the first time i've seen this. by they way, do you have the link to the documentation? i'd like to know more of this. your the author of this one?

Comment: Well the documentation would be the same because it's supposed to be a drop-in replacement but yes there's some things like this that are undocumented. The best documentation should be the [w3c css specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).